# Knocked off a diode during a display motherboard repair, not sure what it does or what it is or does. Please help

Tags: diodes, identification, repair, motherboard

I have an LG ultrafine 5K 27MD5KA-B. The USB-C port became loose inside so I went to repair it. Long story short, that repair requires hot air and I accidentally blew a diode off the board. See images.

One side of each diode pair seems to be connected go ground.

What type of diodes are these and what are they potentially doing? I'll need to order some replacements. The chip they are going to doesn't seem to turn up any results when I search on Google. I thought if I had the datasheet for the chip I could get some clues.

All I know is they seem to be extremely tiny, likely 01005.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

P.S, excuse the flux mess and no that's not solder paste, the chip had a foil like cover which left remnants. [image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those are ESD protection diodes for the high speed USB-C data links. It will be impossible to know what the actual part is.

Just find the diode and solder it back. You need to find it anyway so that it does not cause shorts if left loose on the PCB and it starts moving around.

If you can't find it, it will still work but might get damage while hot-plugging USB cables on that port.

If you want to find a replacement then just search for matching size ESD protection diode that is marketed for the rated speed of the USB link.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have checked the entire board and it's not on the board anywhere. I only noticed it was missing much later and am not entirely sure when it came off. I had Kapton tape around those diodes but I couldn't find it stuck to any of the pieces of tape. It's long gone. I'll have a look for a replacement. By the way, this is for thunderbolt 3 which has a rate of 40 Gbps. How can I translate the speed of the link into diode rating?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the club, same thing just happened to me. After this post I was able to identify a compatible type:

https://www.ti.com/product/TPD1E01B04

since the components are 0.6x0.3mm, it must be 0201.